# Vertically aligning the text of the left div depending on the position of the right div

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I have two parallel div boxes, both containing text. The div boxes don't have a fixed width, it changes percentual. Now the text in the left div box should start at the same position of one heading in the right box, and i dont know how to vertically align them.

```css
#left {
 width: 19%;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 20%;
 text-align: right;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

#right {
 float: left;
 width: 38%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: blue;
 margin-left: 1%;
 text-align: left;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="left">
    <p>This text should be at the same position as the caption "here"</p>
<p>There are also images involved, this should be at the same position as the caption "here2"</p>
  </div>

  <div id="right">

    <p>Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words. </p>

    <h1>here</h1> 

    <p>Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words. </p>
 <h1>here2</h1> 

    <p>Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words. </p>

  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to look like this in the end:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAh5f.png)

And it should also work with some images:

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5sFU.png)

I would be very glad if someone would be able to answer my question, or let me know if something like this isn't possible.

Comment: I think you need Javascript for this

Comment: okay i'll see what i can find, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The first image example could be achieved with javascript - just calculate the height of the right hand box, remove the height of the left hand box and divide by 2 to get the top margin you need to vertically align the left box - or, try this CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  width: 19%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: green;

  margin-left: 20%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20%;

  width: 38%;
  height: auto;

  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 1%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

I would however suggest having a look at bootstrap for building more complex layouts - especially for example 2. It has some powerful layout options available:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: great :) did my solution solve your problem as expected?